# Using a separate thread will increase the performance when you have to return value to the caller?

Tags: java, asynchronous, completable-future

I have a method and in that method, I'm looping a list of Strings with fixed 3 elements in it. Each element is a command that I need to send to a plugin and receive a reference number from the plugin. But between each call, I need to wait about 30 seconds to make sure that the plugin will execute the commands and send a response. I need to have all 3 reference numbers before I return a list of strings from this method. I want to make each plugin calls in a separate thread (CompletableFuture maybe?). But, since I will return all ref.nrs to the caller, does that make it useless to use a separate thread for this job?

Here is the method I call inside the loop from the first method:

```
private String sendToPluginAndGetReference(String command, InputStream in, PrintStream out) {
     CompletableFuture<String> future =
             CompletableFuture.completedFuture(command).thenApplyAsync(reference -> {
                 try {
                     TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(30);
                     reference = sendCommandToPlugin(in, out, command);
                     return reference;
                 } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                     LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                     return null;
                 }});
     try {
         return future.get();
     } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
         LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
         return null;
     }
 }
```

Comment: If you have a lot of commands simultaneously, using thread can still improve performances.
Please note that waiting 30s for the plugin is a bad practice since it could cause crashes if it takes more than 30s to answer in exceptional cases. It also delays the whole system. The plugin should tell when its computation is finished

Comment: create a 3 thread, use cyclic barrier, in run method wait for given time. than execute the task, after task complete call another method

Comment: @SuyashKumarSingh can you write an answer with a code example to make me understand what you are talking about? :)

Comment: @Yonetmen refer this url https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-util-concurrent-cyclicbarrier-java/
see class Computation2  wait for 3000 sec but you should implements Callable